# Threadsafe domain model getOrCreate in SDN?

Tags: thread-safety, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Working with SDN 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Is there a Domain-level, threadsafe way of executing a getOrCreate?

I have

```
@NodeEntity
public class ResourceEntity  extends Entity {

@Fetch
@Indexed(unique=true)
String url;

@Fetch
String platform;
}
```

What I want is to be able to access a neo4j REST database, and either add a new ResourceEntity, or retrieve one already there, if there's already one with a specified url field...

What I can't find is a way of doing that atomically. And it needs to work atomically, as there will be multiple threads calling this code.

```
neo4jTemplate.save(resourceEntity);
```

throws (as it should) a org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException if I attempt to insert a ResourceEntity with a duplicate key, but what *isn't* exposed on Neo4jTemplate at domain level is getOrCreate, which is what I want. How do I achieve that in SDN without having to do something untidy like

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put("url", url);
properties.put("__type__", "com.mydomain.analysis.thingie.dao.ResourceEntity");

Node node = neo4jTemplate.getOrCreateNode("ResourceEntity", "url", "url", properties);
```

...and then pull the new ResourceEntity back from a repository or something similar... nasty!(i haven't tested that but I think that would work) -- but it's VERY ugly!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find an answer to your question? We are facing similar issues, and have in fact implemented your proposed workaround: a getOrCreate function that tries to retrieve a node/edge from the graph using the repository findByPropertyValue function. If no node/edge is found, a new one is created.

The issue with this workaround, is that calling the getOrCreate function using for instance separate JSON calls, causes for distinct getOrCreate transactions to be executed. If these distinct transactions overlap in terms of nodes/edges, duplicate nodes/edges are created if the transactions run simultaneously.

One way to handle this side-effect is to use unique indexes for the node/edge unique id's:
@Indexed(unique = true)

Although this seems an even greater workaround.

Any ideas/best practices from the Neo4j/Spring/SDG people?